# PdfBox Alpha 3.0.0-alpha3 , PDType1Font constructor issue

Tags: java, pdfbox, hung

Good afternoon,

I recently try to upgrade pdfBox to 3.0.0-alpha3.
I align the using of class PDType1font with new constructor requirements:

```
PDType1Font(Standard14Fonts.FontName baseFont)
```

My code now is:

```
FontName font_name_3v= Standard14Fonts.getMappedFontName("HELVETICA_BOLD");
PDFont pdfFont=  new PDType1Font(font_name_3v);
```

But it hung infinite on line :   `PDFont pdfFont=  new PDType1Font(font_name_3v);`

I follow the documentation:

- https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/3.0.0-alpha3/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/font/PDType1Font.html#PDType1Font-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.Standard14Fonts.FontName-
- https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.pdfbox/pdfbox/3.0.0-alpha3/index.html

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

I was missing to specify font family, working code:

```
PDFont pdfFont=  new PDType1Font(font_name_3v.HELVETICA_BOLD);
```

Comment: This is static so use `FontName.HELVETICA_BOLD`

Comment: I've also improved the javadoc for that constructor, hopefully this will be easier to understand.